# Animation in Java ME

Tags: java, animation, java-me, icons

How could I implement animation in Java ME?
I would want to achieve the following, I want to make a List the items in the List are animated icons with some related text description...
I would like to animate all these Icons simultaneously...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot do that with the standard List component. You will need to implement your own or use a third-party component.

UPDATE

I was wrong actually: you can use a CustomItem and have a timer call repaint() every x milliseconds.

Comment: I was wondering if I could animate using the CustomItem class and then inculde that CustomItem into the List.

Comment: You can do that, however I am not sure if the implementation will call the paint() method defined by you. I have not tried that though

Comment: @Ram: abstract class CustomItem has a method "abstract void paint(Graphics g, int w, int h)", so if I subclass CustomItem and override "paint" shouldn't it be called by the implementation to render the CustomItem?

Comment: @Kevin Boyd That reasoning makes sense. I've never tried it either, but it shouldn't be too hard, or too much of a waste of time if it doesn't work, for you to give it a shot.  Just create a two frame Sprite object and see what happens.  Definitely let us know how it works out :)

Comment: The problem here is that you have no control on when the paint() method is called. This is implementation-specific.

Comment: @Maurice: Isn't this the case also with the typical Canvas the callback paint() is called by the implementation.

Comment: No paint cannot or rather should not be invoked directly in an application however, you can call repaint() to have the Canvas object repainted. However in the case of a CustomItem, I am not sure if you can call the repaint as you would call it on a Canvas object. And as Fostah suggested you could try out a Sprite that contains 2 frames. Do let us know how it works out :)